# Displaying data using handlebars based on javascript variable values

Tags: javascript, variables, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have a handlebar data structure which is in this form

```
    var data = [{
    "flightno": "F10001",
    "dept_time": "2100",
    "travel_time": "13.05",
    "origin": "Sydney",
    "destination": "Delhi",
    "infant": "No",
    "recliner": "No",
    "Premium": "1",
    "Economy": "2",
    "Business": "3"
}];
```

And i am getting the origin and destination into javascript variable through a form.
Now i need to display data from the handlebars array that contains the corresponding values to those js variables.

To further clarify if i have 2 js variables with an origin and destination values respectively , i need to search the data array for those origin and destination and then display all of the attributes using each helper .

```
{{#each this}}
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="chosenflight" value="{{flightno}}"></td>
<td>{{flightno}}</td>
<td>{{dept_time}}</td>
<td>{{formatTravelTime travel_time}}</td>
<td>{{Premium}}</td>
<td>{{Economy}}</td>
<td>{{Business}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to filter your array before passing it to handlebars. You can do it using javascript Like

```
 var origin = "Sydney";
 var dest = "Delhi";

 var modData = data.filter(function(obj) {
     return obj.origin.toLowerCase() === origin.toLowerCase() && obj.destination.toLowerCase() === dest.toLowerCase();
 });

 console.log(modData);
```

Comment: I dont need only those 2 values, i need the whole array if the value in the js variables matches with those in the array.

Comment: @SagarSammy The filter will return an array of matching objects whose origin and destination matches with the ones provided above.

Comment: thanks that worked flawlessly, passed modData to template and recompiled it.